# Is getting really drunk and dancing going to solve anything?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Purgatory, I have the option to interact with a couple of unique items.  They seem like throwaway interactions, but I'm curious if they have any in-game use.

At the bar, I can take a drink.  I've only done this a couple of times, but it seems like I can just keep drinking if I so choose.

Elsewhere in the club, I can do a bit of dancing.  Shepard really owns the dance floor, but I can't help but wonder if there's anything to be gained here.

Is there any reason to get really plastered and do a bit of dancing?  (Aside from trying to forget that the apocalypse is in full swing)

Comment: I've talked with three characters so far who have made fun of Shepard's dancing.

Comment: Is there any reason *not* to?

Comment: @TimStone Upload a video of you doing a better job of it (dancing), and you've got yourself an up vote on that comment.

Comment: Huh, I wasn't able to do any of these upon my first visit to Purgatory and was a bit disappointed. I guess it... unlocks or something? O.o

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes It didn't become available to me until sometime after my second or third Priority mission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.**

You are neither awarded, nor reprimanded in any way for doing either of these. They are, as you said, throwaway interactions. There are a couple of humorous moments to be found by doing so, however.

> If you meet **Jack** in Purgatory and speak with her, you can actually dance with her... After she mocks your lack of finesse on the dance floor.

In addition to Shepard showcasing his dance moves, which are obviously centuries more advanced than anyone else on Earth (except maybe @TimStone from the looks of his comment above), drinking at the bar **three** times causes Shepard to back away and black out. He wakes up laying on the couch where **Aria T'Loak** is seated. The two share an awkward glance, and Shepard returns to his cavorting across the galaxy, saving the world, as is his way.

Comment: Ohhhh man, I stopped one drink short of this.  I'm totally going back now...

Comment: and if you drink on more round of 3 glasses, you end up outside the club with people looking down on you, like you are some drunk homeless

Answer (score -2):

After the second drinking "binge" the option disappears.